# ExpressJS session user data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I use an npm for logging my users in via steam. Now what I do when the user has been authenticated I parse the user object into his session, and I add a few elements from the corresponding database row.

Problem is; whenever an user just casually refreshes the page the data from the database (like his balance etc.) is not updated, how can I make it so whenever an user refreshes I update his information?

Comment: your problem is that you loose sessions on page refresh? try saving it in the cookies or local storage..

Comment: Without knowing how you setup the session handling and how you store the data in the session it is not possible to tell where the problem is and how to solve it.

Comment: @t.niese I mean I use `steam-auth` which probably no one on here uses.. I just need to retrieve data from the database and pass it into the session when an user refreshes his page.

Comment: Not knowing the module is not necessarily a problem, as many modules work in a similar way. But again without seeing the relevant code, how you set up the session storage and how you use that module it is not possible to tell what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% what you want but could you put a get request to your dB in window.onload (or componentDidMount in react)?